# Using WCF-Custom to process a tableop select query returns the original message.. not data

Tags: c#, sql-server, biztalk

I've created a message with this syntax which was created by the schema.

[image: Input Message Select]

My orchestration takes the message in and passes it to a Request/Response send shape. The response results are then passed to a Send port. I created my Soap Action header using the configuration created by the generated file.  The action header throws a warning, but there are no errors. When I check the response folder it contains the original input message as shown above. It acts like its not even hitting SQL Server.  Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this. I've built an insert application also, and it works fine.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for us to answer.  If you put message body tracking on and look at the message receive back, what do you see?  What writes it message to the output folder?  A send port with a filter, or the Orchestration?  If so give details. Please use the [edit] link to add details to the question.

Comment: It shows the message coming in, on the receive port, then the same message going to the send port (request/response). The SQL response is received by a receive port. The output send port (going to the folder) is the same message type as the response.

Comment: Also, when I created my generated object and set it up to do a select on a table, it generated my tableoperation schema and Table.dbo schema. Is this schema just used by BizTalk?

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL response be received on the send port, e.g. it should be a request/response send port?

Comment: It is.. I just gave it the same message type as the incoming message.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake. I assumed that a send/response was two operations. Select and SelectResponse. Once I changed the SoapActionHeader to: TableOp/Select/dbo/M351SR  it worked.  thanks for the help